# How can I use System.__ComObject?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm building a scanner app in Xamarin.Forms for a HoneyWell scanner device.
The first version will just be Windows.

In the shared project I've created IScannerService interface which will be used for dependency injection. The interface contains an OnScan event.

In my UWP project I've implemented this interface in my ScannerService class.

It uses the PointOfService.BarcodeScanner to use the device's attached scanner.
(following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792060(v=winembedded.81).aspx)
This all works well except:

In my eventhandling method:

```
private void ClaimedScanner_DataReceived(ClaimedBarcodeScanner sender, BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(args.Report.ScanData);
    var output = dataReader.ReadString(args.Report.ScanData.Length);
    OnScan?.Invoke(sender, output);
}
```

The `args.Report.ScanData` returns an `System.__ComObject` instead of my expected `IBuffer`.

I've tried to figure out what this `System.__ComObject` actually is but I don't really get it. But most of all I don't understand why I'm getting it instead of the type I expect.

How can I use this object so my `output` will be a valid string?

Comment: Did you try casting it?

Comment: Yes I did. The result came up empty when I scan. So I don't know if it just doesn't give me anything or that casting it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: what do you mean it was empty? The object casted successfully but the properties were just null? Also did you try `.GetType()` on it?

Comment: The IBuffer data had a length on 0, that's what I ment by empty.
I have not yet tried .GetType().
We went with a workaround because we found out we might be dealing with an API version problem, but I might try this in an own project later, thx